# meteor + cordova libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception

Tags: xcode, cordova, meteor

I have been playing around with Meteor's command "meteor run ios-device", and it all worked well.

But after a certain build, the app is freezing at the splash screen and Xcode is showing the following error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception
```

The full console output can be seen here http://pastebin.com/Ta98RkAH

After searching on google/stackoverflow it seems like a lot of people get this error for different reasons, but i can't really tell as i'm not familiar with this error and Xcode at all.

One thing i found on [phonegap community](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/-phonegap-run-ios-command-throws-error-after-xcode-upgraded-to-6-0-1-on-phonegap-3-5-0-0) was someone saying npm's package "ios-sim" should be updated, but that did not work for me.

Comment: Same problem here... Did you ever find your way around of it?

Comment: to be honest my develop environment moved to another computer and the error stopped and i did not come back to the previous on to check what was going on //=